# How to sum elements with same index in arrays within differents rows in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'll explain what I need to do in Hive with an example.
I'm receiving two rows:
First row with an array like that (1,3,6,7)
Second row                        (3,6,7,1) 
Result I need                     (4,9,13,8)

So, I need to sum all elements of the firsts index of all arrays of all rows together and the same with the seconds index and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

base table :

```
hive> select values from t1;
1,3,6,7
3,6,7,1
```

Explode with positions

```
hive> select pos,value from t1 lateral view posexplode (split(values,",")) a as pos, value;
0   3
1   6
2   7
3   1
0   1
1   3
2   6
3   7
```

Sum by position

```
hive> select pos,sum(cast(value as int)) from t1 lateral view posexplode (split(values,",")) a as pos, value group by pos;
0   4
1   9
2   13
3   8
```

Collect the sum values as list

```
hive> select collect_list(sumvalue) from (select sum(cast(value as int)) as sumvalue from t1 lateral view posexplode (split(values,",")) a as pos, value group by pos)s;
[4,9,13,8]
```